# microservice showing errors on Dev environment

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have no idea what kind of errors are these and how it is related to microservice when i m not using any message converting in the code. Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance! Any idea on below errors?

```
    2020-09-08 04:13:54.304 ERROR [uniban-service,129475cb8b32b7ad,0053b1e337a7defb,true] 11 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke method; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could Not Convert Output
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:167)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:359)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:68)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could Not Convert Output
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.convertOutputValueIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:674)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:600)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.get(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:463)
at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.get(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:448)
at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.get(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:86)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor79.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:266)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:112)
... 19 more

    2020-09-08 04:13:54.304 DEBUG [uniban-service,129475cb8b32b7ad,0053b1e337a7defb,true] 11 --- 
    [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 
    'bean 'errorChannel'', message: ErrorMessage 
    [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to invoke method; nested 
    exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could Not 
    Convert Output, headers={b3=129475cb8b32b7ad-0053b1e337a7defb-1, id=35b1a363-aa5e-ada3-0c23- 
    5347c337d951, timestamp=1599552834304}]
    2020-09-08 04:13:54.304 DEBUG [uniban-service,129475cb8b32b7ad,0053b1e337a7defb,true] 11 --- 
    [ask-scheduler-4] o.s.c.s.i.m.TracingChannelInterceptor    : Will finish the current span after 
    completion LazySpan(129475cb8b32b7ad/0053b1e337a7defb)
```

Comment: Are you using Kafka streams?

Comment: Where you are getting this error ? In Eureka Zuul. Please explain a little bit more about what changes you did after that it happened

Comment: yes microservice is deployed in Eureka and Config. No Kafka and no SFTP or polling involved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate project configurations and everything about where you are getting the error and where did you deployed? Project config will also help to identify the cause easily

Comment: Configurations are set in properties file which i m reading in the code and the application is deployed on Eureka Server and Config server. is it could be bcos of not properly deployed on environment.

Comment: here are some other logs too in Admin-service :

Comment: `2020-09-08 07:52:55.332  WARN [admin-service,,,] 11 --- [or-http-epoll-6] d.c.b.admin.server.services.InfoUpdater  : Couldn't retrieve info for Instance(id=5c4c9e644a89, version=3, registration=Registration(name=UNIBAN-SERVICE, managementUrl=http://d528bbf7ef1e:8887/uniban-service/admin/actuator, healthUrl=http://d528bbf7ef1e:8887/uniban-service/admin/actuator/health, serviceUrl=http://d528bbf7ef1e:8888, source=discovery), registered=true,

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: d528bbf7ef1e: Name or service not known
 at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
 |_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET info [DefaultWebClient]
Stack trace:
  at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
  at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221190/discussion-between-amit-mishra-and-dimple-hassani).

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. My bug is caused by the jolokia-core. When I upgrade springboot, I do not upgrade springbootadmin synchronously[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UADqD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6BIx.png)

Comment: my issue was solved by adding @EnableCircuitbreaker, although it wasnt using that but may be there was dependency due to other microservices.